# Spring Boot - Count User Requests

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am having a HandlerInterceptor which intercepts all the user request to the Spring Boot app. I am trying to find a way to hold the number of requests that came to the application. The Map I have below is always printing the size of 1 and not getting increased for each new request. Can some one help me on this

```
public class UserLoggingInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor  {

    private static HashMap<String,String> userManagement = new HashMap<String,String>();

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {
        userManagement.put("Another User Added :- ", "1");
        System.out.println("userManagement.size() is "+userManagement.size());
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you always put the same key and the same value to the map. Why should its size change? Why don't you just increment a counter to count? You don't need any map. An AtomicInteger will do.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet . I didnt realize my mistake